# Getting DNS error when accessing app from app catalog site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, dns

I wanted to create an app which will access data across site collections so I downloaded code sample from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Use-the-6b3e4c1e#content).

I published this VS solution so I got app package in solution BIN folder. I uploaded that app on my app catalog site and then add this app in same app catalog site so it's showing in "Site contents".

I clicked on the app which redirected me to app site but I didn't see it, instead I got below error on the page

> [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "app-1be620271cad00.spapp" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

BTW **Fiddler** is installed on my DEV machine.

This error is saying something about the DNS settings so I googled and found below articles which says I need to setup some DNS related stuff, but how can I do this?

I don't have any DNS Manager on my DEV machine? Is there any other way to solve this?

[Bamboo Solutions Blog](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/12/11/user-s-guide-to-configuring-an-environment-for-apps-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-how-to-configure-the-domain-names-in-dns.aspx)

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/how24/archive/2013/06/14/prepare-your-sharepoint-2013-farm-for-app-development-and-debugging.aspx)

Comment: One more if i deployed this app from Visual Studio without adding to app catalog, i can see the app site in app domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS entry was missing in hosts file for my app domain. I add it and it get resolved.

Refer this [blog post](http://sandippatilblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/acess-data-from-other-site-collection-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps.html)